# How does one add a sub widget from a python file to a super widget defined in a kivy file?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a BoxLayout defined in a kivy file, and I am trying to add a label to this BoxLayout from a python file. Below are my python and kivy scripts. When I try to run the program as is, it fails, and I get an error message stating:

**"properties.pyx", line 654, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:9590)
 KeyError: 'box'**

How can I add a label (defined in dummy.py) to the BoxLayout (defined in dummy.kv) from dummy.py?

dummy.py shown below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('dummy.kv')


class test(BoxLayout):
    box = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        label = Label(text='Hello')
        self.ids.box.add_widget(label)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

dummy.kv shown below:

```
#:kivy 1.8

<test>:
    box: box
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: box
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize your `test` class properly:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('dummy.kv')


class test(BoxLayout):
    box = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        label = Label(text='Hello')
        super(test,self).__init__()   #-------ADD THIS LINE
        print(self.ids)
        self.ids.box.add_widget(label)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the solution. It at least appears to work on my machine.

Comment: kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x10a907140>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x10a905fc0>

Answer (score 0):

If those are really your filenames, the kv file is never loaded, so the BoxLayout with id 'box' does not exist. Rename the kv file to `test.kv` or use `kivy.lang.Builder.load_file('dummy.kv')`.

Comment: Thank you. I have added an import statement "from kivy.lang import Builder" and "Builder.load_file('dummy.kv')", as can be seen in the edited code block above. However, I am still getting the same error. Please advise.

Comment: Is the indentation in your pasted code the same as the indentation in the real file?

Comment: Oops. Now it is. I just now indented the line that contains "box: box" in the kivy file to fix it. It now has exactly the same indentation as my actual code.